# android text not showing in button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

This happens very frequently to me when starting to work on android. The text within the button element is not showing fully. What can be wrong? I tried text direction, alignment, gravity but nothing works.

[image]

The code behind it:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/latestButtonString"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton" />
```

Please help and much appreciated.

Update: This is the roundbutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
 <solid android:color="#ABABAB"/> 
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
  android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Add android:gravity="center" in button

Comment: Can you post your xml code....

Comment: The xml is added up and there not much else to add except for textview shown in snapshot. I tried gravity but not working :(

Comment: Show your drawable/roundButton xml file... There must be problem in that file...

Comment: did you test in emulator!?

Comment: maybe its not your button's fault.. try changing its parent's parameters..

Comment: there is no problem with this. can you please share your full xml

Comment: Can you check your styles.xml? I was able to replicate your problem by adding a paddingLeft on the Button.

Comment: Post your entire layout `xml` file.

Comment: @Hardik it worked well when deployed to phone! Thanks.

Comment: @spacemonkey its problem of your editor, close your all windows of editor and restart. it will be normal!!:)

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem, I solved it by chaning the xml for the button from using tools: to android: for the text attribute. Example below (last line is the line thats changed):

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            tools:text="App Settings" />
```

becomes...

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#F6F6F6"
            android:text="App Settings" />
```

Answer (score 3):

try to replace 
     android:text="@string/latestButtonString"

and put direct hardcode string here
as,

```
 android:text="hello"
```

## or

try to replace this line in  roundbutton.xml:

```
<android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
```

with

```
<android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="3dp">
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check by removing `android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"` from your button attribute. If text shown fully, then you need to modify the `@drawable/roundbutton"` there may be you have set `fixed width` thus your text in button is not fully visible.

Comment: I already tried that and nope the text didn't show. It only shows if I change the layout_width="300dip" but not event centered. And this is not an accepted solution

Comment: just a confusion, can you please check `@string/latestButtonString` is there which you want to see.

Comment: Your `Roundbutton` is ok, checked it.

Comment: have you checked emulated output, sometimes eclipse renders wrong due to some glitch.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a `paddingLeft` on your `Button`. Can you check if this is present in your `styles.xml`?

If it is in your `styles.xml`, it is probably important for the theme of your app.

If you would just want to cancel it in that certain `Button`, just put

```
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem...following attribute made it work:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove these line **android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"** but view not create like you if you want to create same view please try these code :

**code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbutton">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="latestButtonString"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: view]